# Array: issues declaring

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I've been trying to convert my python to C code and it's my first time using C.

Basically I want it to ask how many grades I will input and then put them in an array. The problem is that the amount keeps putting in the array. I thought that I could declare the size of the array after asking how many grades I was inputting but I think that's the problem. I am not sure how else to do it. I have a lot of `printf`s I was using for debugging.

Any Suggestions?

```
double enter_quiz_grades()
{

    int quiz_amount,loop,i;
    printf("Enter number of quiz grades to enter:");
    scanf(" %d \n", &quiz_amount);
    printf("You typed %d students\n",quiz_amount);
    double temp=0;
    double grades[quiz_amount];

    for (loop = 0; loop<quiz_amount;loop++)
    {
        printf("loop is %d", loop);
        i = loop+1;
        printf("Enter grade for quiz %d: ",i);
        scanf("%lf\n", &temp);
        grades[loop] = temp;
        printf("%lf",grades[loop]);
    }
    return 0.0; 
}
```

Comment: The problem is "\n" in scanf. Remove \n in all scanfs. It will work as you expected.

Comment: You don't need the `temp` variable, you can scan directly into the array: `scanf("%lf", &grades[loop])`

Comment: As it stands, you don't really need the `grades` array.  If you are later planning to 'return the grades', you are going to run into several problems, one of them being that `return grades;` would be attempting to return a pointer to a local variable that is no longer valid once the function exits.  Another problem will be how to communicate with the calling code how many entries are in the array.  The issues are resolvable — dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` and a pointer to a length variable, for example — but it will be easy to astray.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using '\n' inside scanf. Also you can get rid of additional variables.
Here is the modified code:

```
double enter_quiz_grades() {

    int quiz_amount, i;
    printf("Enter number of quiz grades to enter:");
    scanf("%d", &quiz_amount);
    printf("You typed %d students\n",quiz_amount);
    double temp = 0;
    double grades[quiz_amount];

    for (i = 0; i < quiz_amount; i++)
    {
        printf("loop is %d\n", i);
        printf("Enter grade for quiz %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%lf", &grades[i]);
        printf("%lf\n",grades[i]);
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much guys and declaring the array like how i did is alright too?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small detail, not strictly related to the original question:

```
double grades[quiz_amount];
```

This creates an array, sized at runtime, from a variable. If this variable is read from somewhere, this can lead to a malicious user giving it a very high (or ngative!) value, and you are in big problems. The linux kernel is removing them from the source for this exact reason (as this syntax creates the array in the stack - attacker can modify the return address). Make this a dynamic array allocated on the heap (`malloc()`).

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Kills-The-VLA